# HookWebpackError: EMFILE: too many open files, When execute npm run export

Tags: next.js

According to [this link](https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-nextjs-deploy/)

I have configured my  package.json project file using these code snipped:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "export": "npm run build && next export -o _static",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

But when I run the command: `npm run export` in the terminal, It causes errors:

```
Failed to compile.

HookWebpackError: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'E:\Projects\React\dastshafa-final\node_modules\@mui\icons-material\SixKOutlined.js'
    at makeWebpackError (E:\Projects\React\dastshafa-final\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:41664:9)
    at E:\Projects\React\dastshafa-final\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:25354:12
    at eval (eval at create (E:\Projects\React\dastshafa-final\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:140346:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at E:\Projects\React\dastshafa-final\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:22805:26
    at E:\Projects\React\dastshafa-final\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:327:36
-- inner error --
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'E:\Projects\React\dastshafa-final\node_modules\@mui\icons-material\SixKOutlined.js'
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'E:\Projects\React\dastshafa-final\node_modules\@mui\icons-material\SixKOutlined.js'


> Build failed because of webpack errors
```

I can not find a good solution for it please help. tnx

OS:Windows 8.1
Node.js:18

**Edit**

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dastshafa-final",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "export": "npm run build && next export -o _static",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.2",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "next": "12.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-simple-star-rating": "^4.0.5",
    "react-toastify": "^8.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.11.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What packages do you use? Give full package.json

Comment: please check out the edit section

Answer (score 6):

I also got this error while running `npm run build` on a next.js project styled with Material UI

The issue was that by importing MUI components like this:

```
import {Paper} from "@mui/materials"
import {Cancel} from "@mui/icons-materials"
```

I am not just importing the `<Paper />` and `<Cancle />` mui components, but the entire @mui libraries. Hence, `HookWebpackError: EMFILE: too many open files`, increasing the bundle size

See https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/ for more info.

I also did not like the look of this:
`import * as React from react`

So this is what is changed things to to work:

```
import React from "react"
import Paper from "@mui/materials/Paper"
import Cancel from "@mui/icons-materials/Cancel"
```

Comment: Worked thanks! We should not import all icons-material lib. We should import it like: import StorefrontIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Storefront';

Comment: what a fool is mui

Comment: For anyone trying to solve this problem, and keep doing named imports, you can config the feature modularized imports from Next.js 13.1 in next.config. 

See here:
https://youtu.be/_q1K7cybyRk?t=191

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error while building NextJS project (12.0.10), I've fixed these by importing mui icons directly without destructing,

Getting Error while build

```
import { ShoppingCart } from "@mui/icons-material";
```

Able to build

```
import ShoppingCartIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCart";
```

Comment: For anyone trying to solve this problem, and keep doing named imports, you can config the feature modularized imports from Next.js 13.1 in next.config. See here: https://youtu.be/_q1K7cybyRk?t=191

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got an answer.
It is nothing but a memory leak, Every time Ram is occupied with programs, we encounter this error. The solution is to close additional programs or upgrade the system RAM.

tnx and congratulations

Answer (score 1):

me fixed by executing `rm -rf node_modules` and `rm yarn.lock` (if you're using yarn) or `rm package-lock.json` (if you're using npm)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution that worked for me was deleting .next file in my project and then running the command again.

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

just update Nextjs to 13.5.4 version and it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).